# Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, adonis.js

Here is my **customer_schema.js** file:

```
up () {                                                                                                                                        
    this.create('customers', (table) => {                                                                                                        
      table.increments()                                                                                                                         
      table.string('name', 30)                                                                                                                   
    })                                                                                                                                           
  }
```

**CustomerSeed.js:**

```
class CustomerSeeder {                                                                                                                           
  async run () {                                                                                                                                 
    const customer = await Factory                                                                                                               
      .model('App/Models/Customer')                                                                                                          
      .create()                                                                                                                              
    console.log('customer: ')                                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                                              
}
```

The **Customer.js** model is "empty "

I run the migrations, all is Ok, but can not run the seeds : `adonis seed` throws this  error message:

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',                                                                                                                    
  errno: 1054,                                                                                                                                   
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list'",                                                                                     
  sqlState: '42S22',                                                                                                                             
  index: 0,                                                                                                                                      
  sql:                                                                                                                                           
   "insert into `customers` (`created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`) values ('2019-03-04 20:01:17', 'Peter Walsh', '2019-03-04 20:01:17')" }
```

Why this happens? I did not even declare `table.timestamps()` in my schema file and :

```
describe customers;                                                                                                                              
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+                                                                             
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |                                                                             
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+                                                                             
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |                                                                             
| name  | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |                                                                             
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+                                                                             
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
  static get createdAtColumn () {
    return null;
  }

  static get updatedAtColumn () {
    return null;
  }
```

Add this 2 functions to your model, it should work :)

Comment: I did what you suggested but I am getting the issue. The weird thing is that my MySQL table does not have those columns at all as my schema file did not declare them. +1 for the effort though

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention it in my question but I used `database/factory.js` to seed the table. Thank you

Comment: I use MySQL database

Comment: That is a lot of effort you did, thank you :) I tried that solution before when you gave me the link to the documentation

Comment: I checked the difference between your code and mine: in my `updatedAtColumn()` instead of returning `null` I returned `.` (a point), so your very first solution is right. And that is a clean solution for Node.js application ( from what I read. You spent a lot of effort on this, you have my respect Man. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous good answer, when you have lot of models as the application grows, you can automate the above solution instead of writing it as per model:

```
'use strict'

class NoTimestamp {
  register (Model) {
    Object.defineProperties(Model, {
      createdAtColumn: {
        get: () => null,
      },
      updatedAtColumn: {
        get: () => null,
      },
    })
  }
}

module.exports = NoTimestamp
```

Credit to Romain Lanz who showed me [this](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-fullstack-app/blob/master/app/Models/Traits/NoTimestamp.js) solution.